# File extension restriction to .cor (only)

Tags: c#, file

How can I restrict only .cor files to be added to the list. 
The code bellow allows .corx, .corxx, .corxxx to be added to the list. 
I only want .cor files. Is that possible?

```
private void btn_models_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult res = dlg_find_folder.ShowDialog();
    if (res == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        tbx_models.Text = dlg_find_folder.SelectedPath;

        populateChecklist(tbx_models.Text, "cor");
        cbx_all.CheckState = System.Windows.Forms.CheckState.Checked;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Function populates the models checklist based on the models found in the specified folder.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="directory">Directory in which to search for files</param>
/// <param name="extension">File extension given without period</param>
private void populateChecklist(String directory, String extension)
{
    clb_run_list.Items.Clear();

    System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator;
    String mdl_name;

    try
    {
        enumerator = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*." + extension).GetEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            mdl_name = parse_file_name((String)enumerator.Current, directory, extension);
            clb_run_list.Items.Add(mdl_name);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        //above code will fail if the initially specified directory does not exist
        //MessageBox.Show("The specified directory does not exist. Please select a valid directory.");
    }

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a check for `FileName.EndsWith(extension)`  before adding to your list?

Comment: The problem was in the parse_file_name method (not created by me). The offset was wrong. So once I took that out, and used your recommendation things started to look brighter... I was able to figure it out Thanks To All especially Ian....

Answer (score 4):

How about;

```
if (Path.GetExtension(mdl_name).Equals(".cor", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  clb_run_list.Items.Add(mdl_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an artifact of Windows support for old DOS 8.3 filenames.  Files with an extension like .corxxx get mapped to a 8.3 name like Blah~1.cor.  And will match your wildcard.

Nothing you can do but double-check the filename you get.  Use Path.GetExtension()

Comment: Yep, indeed it is very interesting to read the remarks (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx). Only extensions with three chars are handled like this. And only with the `*` wildchar. Not quite what I call intuitive.